# CKAN - customizing data fields

Tags: python, ckan

I've followed the Ckan example Customizing dataset and resource metadata fields using IDatasetForm [here](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/adding-custom-fields.html#customizing-dataset-and-resource-metadata-fields-using-idatasetform) and I get to add some custom datafields.

Then, I would like to add some dictionaries and I've followed these steps [here](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/adding-custom-fields.html#tag-vocabularies) and everything is working at the very first time.

I spent few time since I realised it seems vocabularies are created only once.

1. I added the following function:

   ```
   def create_country_codes():
       user = tk.get_action('get_site_user')({'ignore_auth': True}, {})
       context = {'user': user['name']}
       try:
           data = {'id': 'country_codes'}
           tk.get_action('vocabulary_show')(context, data)
       except tk.ObjectNotFound:
           data = {'name': 'country_codes'}
           vocab = tk.get_action('vocabulary_create')(context, data)
           for tag in (u'uk', u'ie', u'de', u'fr', u'es'):
               data = {'name': tag, 'vocabulary_id': vocab['id']}
               tk.get_action('tag_create')(context, data)
   ```
2. The first time was everything OK and I get it the result as I expected as I said. Then I tried to add more countries (tags) into the function and I was stuck because it seems didn't update what I've changed:

   ```
   ...
    for tag in (u'uk', u'ie', u'de', u'fr', u'es', u'aa', u'bb', u'cc', u'dd'):
               data = {'name': tag, 'vocabulary_id': vocab['id']}
               tk.get_action('tag_create')(context, data)
   ...
   ```

   **Notice new tags: u'aa', u'bb', u'cc', u'dd'**
3. After few time I tried to change the name of the function and then I get the list of all countries as I wanted. I guess that de list of tags is created at the first time.

I don't know if maybe I'm doing something wrong, but does someone know how to update the list of vocabulary (without creating a new function)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found the following helpful extension that provides a way to configure different schemas of datasets and to customize fields: [CKAN-scheming](https://github.com/open-data/ckanext-scheming)

Hope it helps to anybody in my situation :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi sorry was the late reply..I bumped into this while looking for something else similar. Anyway if your list gets updated then you have to call 
 `vocab = tk.get_action('vocabulary_update')(context, data)` 
**Instead of**  `vocab = tk.get_action('vocabulary_create')(context, data)`  once you have checked that the list has been updated